# how do u draw a Transparent line on an image with PIL?

Tags: python

here's what I got:

```
draw.line([(x1,y1),(x2,y2)],fill = (255, 255, 255))
```

the result is a white line, 
but I want a transparent one, 
what should I do?

Comment: You want to draw a line in [transparent ink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg)?

Comment: You might want to try Googling your question's exact title, by the way. I did that and found several useful results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line function takes either an RGB or an RGBA value to my knowledge.

Try:

```
draw.line([(x1,y1),(x2,y2)],fill = (255, 255, 255, 0))
```

Comment: it's RGBA that makes it transparent.

Comment: This only seems to work when the image itself is RGBA. Even then, drawing a transparent line over another doesn't blend their values...